# If two non-disjoint subsets are connected, why does their union have to be connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

So X and Y are two sets such that their intersection is nonempty. I want to show that if X and Y are each connected, together their union is connected.

I tried proving this by contraposition and I've thought about it for a while but can't come up with the conclusion.

I suppose that X union Y is not connected. This means that X union Y can be written as a union of two separated sets C and D (meaning no point of C is in the closure of D and vice versa). So C is contained in the intersection of X and Y because the two sets overlap at at least one point. 
Here is where I'm stuck. From this information, how can I conclude that X can be written as a union of two separated sets?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ sets in any topological space, or are they subsets of $R^n$?

Comment: They are in any metric space. thanks for the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do now is show that (at least) one of $X$ and $Y$ has nontrivial intersection with *both* $C$ and $D$. Suppose $X$ is the one. Use this to decompose $X$ into non-intersecting, non-empty open sets, contradicting the connectedness hypothesis.

Comment: Sorry I'm still a little confused. I can see that X can be written as the union of C and D, is that the conclusion? I think I might be complicating it..

Comment: @user1961722 It's not quite the union of $C$ and $D$. It's the union of $X \cap C$ and $X \cap D$ (which are both open in $X$). These are nonempty and have nontrivial intersection.

Comment: that makes sense. And then can I say that X∩C and X∩D are separated because they are subsets of separated sets?

Comment: Yup, @user1961722.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought of this myself. thanks